# What does the Rambam mean by בשרו חם?

Tags: words, rambam, medicine, health-safety-shmira

In [Hilkhot De'ot 3:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/1203.htm) (3:2 in non-Yemenite versions) the Rambam writes:

> For example, a person with warm constitution (בשרו חם) should not eat meat or
>   honey...

What exactly is meant by "warm constitution"? How can a person identify if a person has a "warm" constitution or a "cool" one. Is there a modern-day term by which we refer to this condition?

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference to the 4 humors. A warm constitution I one with a disproportionate amount of blood vs. Phlegm, black bile, and yellow bile.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Compare with [Avos HaTuma 5:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=10490).

Comment: Aren't the 4 of them 2 hot (2 cold, 2 dry and 2 wet). (1 dry cold, 1 dry hot, 1 wet cold and 1 wet hot)

Comment: see https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a1/Humorism.svg     and    https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%97%D7%95%D7%AA